# Iterate values on xml nodes SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I'm trying to extract all the values ​​from each XML node. For example for the `<Cash>` node, I would like to recover the value (0,1) but I can not get it

```
CREATE TABLE #TableXML (Col1 INT PRIMARY KEY, Col2 XML) 

INSERT INTO #TableXML 
VALUES (1,
'<CookedUP>
  <Evenement Calcul="16">
    <Cookie xmlns="http://services.ariel.morneausobeco.com/2007/02" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <AlternateOptionTypeCodes />
      <Cash>0</Cash>
      <CashInterest>0</CashInterest>
      <CashSource>Undefined</CashSource>
      <Code>A</Code>
      <SmallAmount>0</SmallAmount>
      <SmallAmountType>Undefined</SmallAmountType>
    </Cookie>
    <Cookie xmlns="http://services.ariel.morneausobeco.com/2007/02" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <AlternateOptionTypeCodes />
      <Cash>1</Cash>
      <CashInterest>2</CashInterest>
      <CashSource>Undefined</CashSource>
      <Code>B</Code>
      <SmallAmount>1</SmallAmount>
      <SmallAmountType>1</SmallAmountType>
    </Cookie>
  </Evenement>
</CookedUP> '
)

WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://services.ariel.morneausobeco.com/2007/02' AS ns)
SELECT 
    b.Col1,
    x.XmlCol.value('(ns:Cookie/ns:SmallAmount/text())[2]', 'int') AS SmallAmount,
    x.XmlCol.value('(ns:Cookie/ns:Cash/text())[2]', 'int') AS Cash
FROM
    #TableXML b
CROSS APPLY 
    b.Col2.nodes('CookedUP/Evenement') x(XmlCol);
```

Comment: What are your expected results? Do you want all values of a particular column in the same cell?

Comment: for example , In Nodes Code i want to extract values (A,B) in a column called Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small tweak to what you already have and you got it.
The namespaces doesn't come into play until the Cookie node.

I update the example to a table variable, give this a try:

```
DECLARE @TableXML TABLE(Col1 int primary key, Col2 xml) 
Insert into @TableXML values ( 1,
'<CookedUP>
  <Evenement Calcul="16">
    <Cookie xmlns="http://services.ariel.morneausobeco.com/2007/02" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <AlternateOptionTypeCodes />
      <Cash>0</Cash>
      <CashInterest>0</CashInterest>
      <CashSource>Undefined</CashSource>
      <Code>A</Code>
      <SmallAmount>0</SmallAmount>
      <SmallAmountType>Undefined</SmallAmountType>
    </Cookie>
    <Cookie xmlns="http://services.ariel.morneausobeco.com/2007/02" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <AlternateOptionTypeCodes />
      <Cash>1</Cash>
      <CashInterest>2</CashInterest>
      <CashSource>Undefined</CashSource>
      <Code>B</Code>
      <SmallAmount>1</SmallAmount>
      <SmallAmountType>1</SmallAmountType>
    </Cookie>
  </Evenement>
</CookedUP> '
)


;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://services.ariel.morneausobeco.com/2007/02' AS ns)
SELECT b.Col1
        --Also include the namespaces here with ns: for each "field" you are after contained within Cookie
       ,XmlCol.value('(./ns:SmallAmount)[1]', 'int') AS SmallAmount
       ,XmlCol.value('(./ns:Cash)[1]', 'int') AS Cash
       ,XmlCol.value('(./ns:Code)[1]', 'nvarchar(10)') AS Code
       ,XmlCol.value('(./ns:CashSource)[1]', 'nvarchar(10)') AS CashSource
FROM @TableXML b
CROSS APPLY b.Col2.nodes('/CookedUP/Evenement/ns:Cookie') AS x(XmlCol) --ns, the namespace, only at Cookie node.
```